# how can I create Observable form property of the Redux Store State?

Tags: redux, rxjs

I have redux store and state for example :

```
export class CustomerState 
{   
 customerId: Number;  
 customerInformation: any;
}
```

I have access to store in my component and I would like get observable only from customerId.
In angular this can be done by select:

```
@select((s: CustomerState ) => s.CustomerState.customerId)
customerId$: Observable<Number>;
```

but this is redux store and not angular component

Is this possible to achieve in Redux store?

Comment: Not familiar with redux, but if you want some specific properties in your component, have you tried `map()` or `pluck()` ?

Answer (score 0):

In Redux, the store (app state) is an immutable object, meaning it's properties are never changed. Instead, whenever the store is updated, the object is replaced entirely by the new object returned by your reducer function. So you can't actually observe a property of the Store. Instead, you subscribe to changes to the store, which is an observable, and then use a pattern like this one to determine if a property has changed:

https://redux.js.org/api/store#subscribelistener

```
function select(state) {
  return state.some.deep.property
}

let currentValue
function handleChange() {
  let previousValue = currentValue
  currentValue = select(store.getState())

  if (previousValue !== currentValue) {
    console.log(
      'Some deep nested property changed from',
      previousValue,
      'to',
      currentValue
    )
  }
}

const unsubscribe = store.subscribe(handleChange)
unsubscribe()
```